# React Router V4 Path Issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React Router Dom V4, my path to my homepage works but my path to my about page doesn't work.

I'm not sure if it's anything to do with the fact I'm using Xampp or not.

Index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./components/App";
import About from "./components/About";

const Root = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Route path="/" component={App} />
                <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}

render(<Root />, document.getElementById('main'));
```

Header.js

```
import React from "react";

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

About.js

```
import React from "react";

const About = () => {
    return (
        <p>This is the about page</p>
    )
}

export default About;
```

Comment: What do you mean with "does not work". What are you expect it to so, and what does happen instead? And is there something in the console that may help to find the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you use plain html links, so React will not be called when the user clicks the link. You should use the `Link` Element from the router-module.

Try the following for the menu:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
....
<li><Link to='/about'>About</Link></li>
```

Comment: Thanks :)

This works just need to make sure it has a closing '</Link>' tag or you get an error.

P.S. Do you know how to get it to work so if you go to '/about' the page loads. Currently the about page will only work if you click on the header links?